# Trying to implement iCarousel into my project, but nothing's showing up - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I'm trying to use the iCarousel library to implement a carousel type picker in my app, but when I load the view that should display the carousel, nothing appears.

Here's the relevant code:

iCarousel delegate methods:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel {
    return 65;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    // Create a number label representing a numeric WPM option
    UILabel *numberLabel = nil;

    // Create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (!view) {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 220, 60)];
        numberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        numberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        numberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        numberLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        numberLabel.tag = 1;

        [view addSubview:numberLabel];
    }
    else {
        numberLabel = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];
    }

    // Calculate the number's value depending on the index value being retrieved
    int number = 200 + (index * 20);
    numberLabel.text = [@(number) stringValue];

    return view;
}
```

And in `viewDidLoad:`:

```
    self.carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 35, 150, 50)];
    self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
    [self.view addSubview:self.carousel];
```

What exactly am I missing that's messing it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used iCarousel, but maybe you didn't set the delegate and/or dataSource?

```
self.carousel.delegate = self;
self.carousel.dataSource = self;
```

From the code you're showing it doesn't seem like you do.

Answer (score 0):

The above methods are icarousel delegate methods,do check whether they are invoked or not.If not,check whether u have added iCarouselDelegate , iCarouselDataSource in your interface file.Also,you are adding icarousel as a subview.Rather it should be established in the nib file or the storyboard itself,while the numberlabel should be added as a subview inside the carousel view.
Do check whether you are doing anything like this: [carousel reloadData];
This should call all the carousel delegate methods.

Comment: This is the top of my .h file for the file that I use the iCarousel in: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iCarousel.h"

@interface SpeedOptionsController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.carousel.delegate = self;
self.carousel.dataSource = self;
[self.carousel reload];
```